# How to store database password in a program for it to access the database?

Tags: c#

I need my program to be able to connect to some kind of a database (e.g. SQL) and obviously the program needs the password to get access to the database. And setting a hardcoded variable with a password would be more than enough but I want to think like it's a real life situation. So I want it to be stored securely, and hardcoding a password to the code from what I know is not a very good idea. How do I do it then? I searched multiple forums, topics and maybe there was an answer but im not gonna lie it is complicated. Any help?

Comment: Put it in a config file.

Comment: Well, the config file has to still be stored on a user's computer so it is still accessible. So I guess I would have to encrypt it somehow...

Comment: There isn't really much benefit in encrypting it. For the application to read it, it needs to be able to decrypt it. If the application can decrypt it, then people with access to your application can potentially decrypt it. Why is this an issue? The end user needs to secure their machine and their database. Surely you're not distributing an application that directly connects to a centralised database? If so, that's a very bad idea.

Comment: Im not distributing anything. I am a student, I am practising and as I said I want to think like it is a real life situation. My idea is to have a fully funtional program which allows the user to register and login to an application, but for this I need to store the passwords' and logins' somewhere. That is why I need a database, so that is why I am asking, is there any way to make this data exchange secure.

Comment: So it is possible to check if the user's login and password exist in the database without the need of admin login details?

Comment: Look at it this way: if the user has a client application which connects directly to your database, or somehow uses credentials which give access to the database, consider your database to be compromised and that hackers have access to it. This question is way too broad to give an answer to, IMHO, but you need to look into web APIs.

Comment: Okay... See this is why I asked this question. Because the answer is there but it is complicated and hard to understand for a student developer. I would still probably try and figure things out myself, while looking at your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answers! I think I am getting the idea ;D

Answer (score 1):

It's a broad question but the simple answer is that you would not store it but instead make the user provide a password.

Typically you would have an API server between an app and a database rather than allow direct access to the DB. The API would have a route that accepts a username and password and returns a jwt or some other kind of authorization token. Subsequent calls to the API would also send the token, which is used to verify the requests. You can store the authorization token locally but its something you should try to protect from other applications as much as possible.

Comment: So... I need to make the client send user details to the API server which then this server connects to the database which then checks if the details are right and if they are right, then it allows the client to connect to the main program...

Comment: @Dawid the client _never_ talks to the database directly. It always goes through the API.

Comment: Yeah, by details you mean username and password probably. Read up on jwt's and password hashing.

But after that the app will keep calling the API. Only your server should be able to access the DB. It's not safe to let direct access to your DB

Comment: So the server API is basically an Administrator Client which routes all of the requests. I think I start to understrand what you mean. Yeah, because then the Client doesn't get any information as everything is done through an interpretator (The API Server).

Comment: Although then I would need to include the API's Server IP into a clients code, but I guess this is not a problem.

Anyways, Thanks for your time and response! I think I got it ;p